# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ' { '

Tags: magento-1.9, php, error

I probably know that this is something really simple, but I can not figure out what is wrong with my code. I got this

```
    $this->_addButton('Generate', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Generate'),
        'onclick'   =>  jQuery.ajax({url: "Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/generate/generate/')", 
                  method: 'GET', 
                  data: {},
                  success(function() 
                  { alert ('Generation Successful!'); }),
                  error(function() 
                  { alert ('Generation Failed!'); }),
     }),
    ), -1);
```

And I am getting this error:  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\wamp64\www\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Form\Container.php on line 68`

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot some quotes:

```
$this->_addButton('Generate', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Generate'),
        'onclick'   =>  "jQuery.ajax({url: '".Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/generate/generate/')."', 
              method: 'GET', 
              data: {},
              success(function()
              { alert ('Generation Successful!'); }),
              error(function()
              { alert ('Generation Failed!'); }),
 })",
), -1);
```

Comment: @DanteZ. Welcome to SE. If an answer solves your problem, mark it as accepted.

Comment: I can not mark it this early, I had to wait like 10 minutes after I posted the question. Also, is that the correct way to call another function as an event when I click on that button?